# Keyboard Hotkey for comment lines in DataStudio?

Tags: comments, hotkeys, ibm-data-studio

I was searching on internet, but zero results. Anyone knows?

I'm using IBM DataStudio 4.1.1.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the shortcut to turn lines of code into comments then it's **Ctrl + /**

Answer (score 0):

Use "--" double hyphen to comment SQL code in Data studio